# php login and form data copy issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I'm trying to build a simple form with a one box(username) login. I'm using Dreamweaver because it (in theory) makes the php stuff easier.

I have this first page where the user put's their name, it is checked against the database and they can continue if the name is recognised, which works fine.

```
    <?php require_once('Connections/logIn.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Username'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_logIn, $logIn);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE TCR_usr = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "text"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $logIn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['Username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['Username'];
  $password=$_POST['Username'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "TCR_Form.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "index.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_logIn, $logIn);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT TCR_usr, TCR_usr FROM staff WHERE TCR_usr=%s AND TCR_usr=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $logIn) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Timetabling Change Request Form - Log in.</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>


<body>

<div class="MainBoxIndex">
    <div style="width: 250px; height: 150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 175px;">
        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Please log in</h3>

      <form action="<?php echo $loginFormAction;?>" method="POST" name="logIn" target="">

        <p>Username: <input name="Username" type="text" value="" size="20" maxlength="15" >
      </p>
      <Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1">
      </form>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

But after the login I want the username to be passed on to a box on the next page. I can do this using

`<?php $Username = $_POST['Username'];echo $Username ?>`

when the code for the login isnt there on the first page, if the login code is there I get an undefined variable message

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Username in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\TCR_Form.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
```

This is the page that I'm trying to copy the data to

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Timetabling Change Request Form</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>

<div class="MainBox">
    <div class="titleBox">
        <h3>TIMETABLING CHANGE REQUEST FORM</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="staffDetails">
  <h3>Your Details</h3>
        <form action="" method="get" name="TCR_findStaff">
        <p>User: <input type="text" name="Username"
value="<?php $Username = $_SESSION['Username'];echo $Username; ?>">
           Email: <input name="email" type="text" value=""></p>
        <p>Dept: <input name="dept" type="text" value="">
        </p>
    </form></div>

<div class="activityDetails">

        <p>Module Code (e.g 82005)<input name="module" type="text" value=""></p>
  <p>Activity Code(s) affected (e.g 01417s1/01)</p>
    <textarea name="actCodes" cols="80" rows="8"></textarea>

  </div>

    <div class="dateBox">
      <p>Change effective from
      <input name="effectiveDate" type="text" value=""></p>
      <p>URGENT <input <?php if (!(strcmp("effectiveDate","[today]+5"))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> name="urgent" type="checkbox" value="URGENT"></label></p>

    </div>

    <div class="requestBox"></div>

    <div class="reasonBox"></div>

    <div class="decBox"></div>

        </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help fix this please?

Nathan.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store this data within a session first, here is a step by step guide for you which should work:

PHP:

Start off by starting a session (Include this on all pages of your site)

```
Session_Start(); //Usually included at the top of each page
```

From here, once the user has logged in, you can transfer the data they entered straight into the session using:

```
$_SESSION['Username'] = $Username;
```

As you have already set your $Username variable using the following line of code:

```
$Username = $_POST['Username'];
```

Now that it is stored within the session, on your other page you can obtain it into a local variable using the following:

```
$Username = $_SESSION['Username'];
```

And then you can do what you want with this, such as displaying it on screen by echoing it out

```
echo $Username;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that, I see what your getting at. I must be going wrong somewhere though because now the field is just blank. i put this in the second page <p>User: <input type="text" name="Username"
value="<?php $Username = $_SESSION['Username'];echo $Username; ?>">

Comment: No problem, I hope you can get it sorted, I think what your best off doing is just putting that piece of code anywhere "<?php $Username = $_SESSION['Username']; ?>" and then for your value you can just straight out do "<?php echo $Username; ?>"

Comment: Just to test that the username is being stored correctly in the session, try doing a print_r on the session, if you add this code to your php file and try running it, it should give you a result <?php print_r($_SESSION['Username']); ?>

Comment: Sorry to be a pain Alex, I can't seem to conquer this. For some reason or another DW doesn't like it when I put $_SESSION['Username'] = $Username; into the existing session on the first page and I cant get the data across. Can you give me something i can copy/paste in please? I'm running out of time to have this finished. I have edited the original question to show all the code for both pages if this helps?

Comment: Np, I'm happy to try and help, let me look through, and see what I can do.

Comment: I think the problem is, theirs quite a lot to your code, I could probably re-make you a basic login system if you like, to be like a substitute for you until you manage to get the more advanced stuff included?

Comment: Right, I've re-submitted a new answer, it's a basic login system, with abit of validation in place, and other features, it should work, give it a go and let me know how it goes for you, just change the table name and columns to suit your MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Right.. I've redone all the code for you, this is for the Login.php page, or what ever you want to call it, taking in note if you do change it, remember to change the form action to your new address.

I've done this to suit your code as well as I could, there is only one line of code you should need to change here, which is the $sql code, where you will need to put your own table names and columns, If you see if this works first, and if it does, I'll sort out your next page for you if you need assistance with that, I hope this helps, I've tried my best.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Connect to database -->
<?php require_once('Connections/logIn.php'); 

//Start a session
Session_Start();

//Obtain the username typed into the form and store it in a variable '$Username'
$Username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);

//Obtain the password typed into the form and store it in a variable '$Password'
$Password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);

//BASIC VALIDATION
//IF username and password exist
if($Username && $Password)
{
    //Create a login
    //YOU NEED TO EDIT THESE DEPENDING ON YOUR MYSQL TABLE NAMES AND HEADINGS
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE UserName = '$UserName' and Password = '$Password' LIMIT 1");

    //Declare/verify that $sql is a mysql_query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    //Count the amount of data that is received
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //Validate to ensure only one piece of user info has been obtained
    if($count==1)
    {
        //Store this information in a SESSION VARIABLE
        $_SESSION['Username'] = $Username;

        //For test purposes to see if it works - Can remove later
        echo "Success";

        //Also Lets see if the Session successfully stored the username..
        //Can also remove this later..
        print_r($_SESSION['Username']);
    }

}

//ELSE IF USERNAME AND PASSWORD DON'T EXIST (A form field has been left blank)
else 
{
    echo "Please enter your username and password";
}

?>

<form action='Login.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='UserName' placeholder='Username'>
    <input type='password' name='Password' placeholder='Password'>
    <input type='submit' name='Login' value='Log In'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```